# Query products on category and tag together

Tags: wordpress

I want to be able to filter products based on category and tag, as well as sub category and tag. From my research I heard that I must write some kind of rewrite rule in functions.php for this to be possible - is that correct?

My settings:

- Category Base: category
- Tag Base: tag

Desired URL Structure:

- xyz.com/category/soccer/tag/adidas
- xyz.com/category/soccer/without-laces/tag/adidas

---

I've noticed that this works:
hey.com/category/soccer/without-laces/?tag=adidas

But not this....

hey.com/category/soccer/without-laces/tag/adidas

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), and what specific problem you need help with. See the [ask] page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Hello, as @HowardE said: StackOverflow is designed to solve coding problems, means we need to see a specific technical issues accompanied with a coding attempts, StackOverflow is not designed to work on others projects.